# Evaluate the contour integral $\int_γ\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2} dz $

Tags: contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have the following question which i am trying to solve using Cauchy’s Integral Formula (nothing else)

> Let $γ$ denote the positively oriented circular contour of radius 1
> about 0.
>
> Evaluate the contour integral $\int_γ\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2} dz $

I find that $\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2}$ has singularites at $z=0$ and $z=1/2$

So i subdivide the interior of $\gamma$ as follows:

> [image: Blockquote]

Then we have $\int_γ\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2} dz =\int_{γ_1}\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2} dz +\int_{γ_2}\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2} dz $ .

So i let $f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z4(z-1/2)} $

Thus we have: $\int_{γ_1}\frac{(z^2+1)}{z(2z-1)^2} dz= \int_{γ_1}\frac{f(z)}{(z-1/2)} dz =2\pi i f(1/2) $

However this would give my $f$ has being undefined.

I was wondering if this question can be solve by Cauchy’s Integral Formula, the questions actually says to use Cauchy’s formula for Derivatives but i wanted to see if both formula gives the right answer.

So my question is how would i use Cauchy’s Integral Formula when there is the "same singularites twice" (in this case $z=1/2$).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula. Cauchy's formula for derivatives is, essentially, a generalization for Cauchy's integral formula when the zero has order $k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have higher order poles, you cannot apply the Cauchy integral formula directly, simply because the assumptions of the theorem are *not* satisfied; particularly, your function $f$ is not holomorphic in any simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing the contour.

If you proceed with the Cauchy integral formula, you would end up with following the steps of *proving* the higher order Cauchy integral formula, which uses the derivatives of the function $f$.